# Uploading multiple files with nodemailer/sendgrid

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid, multer

Is there a way to upload multiple attachments to Sendgrid with Nodemailer/Express/Multer? I'm able to send a single file but thoroughly testing with an array of attachments failed.

**This is my controller function where i submit the files:**

```
    $scope.submitEmail = function(email) {

    var formData = new FormData();

    $scope.email.to = $scope.email_employer;


    formData.append('from', $scope.email.from);
    formData.append('to', $scope.email.to);
    formData.append('subject', $scope.email.subject);
    formData.append('text', $scope.email.text);        

    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
    var files = fileSelect.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];

      // Add the file to the request.
      formData.append('attachment', file, file.name);
    }

    /*
    Object.keys($scope.email).forEach(function(key) {
        formData.append(key, $scope.email[key]);
    });
    */

    $http.post('/api/email', formData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then(function(data, status) {

        console.log("Sent ok");

    }, function(data, status) {

        //here we have to add an error message e.g. "We could not send the form at this moment. Try again later"
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

This is my app.js where i try to send the file to Sendgrid

```
// Set default node environment to development
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config/environment');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' });
//var upload = multer();

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

var options = {
  auth: {
    api_user: '##########',
    api_key: '###########'
 }
}

var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));


// Setup server
var app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);


app.post('/api/email', upload.array('attachment', 4), function(req, res, next)     {

console.log(req.file);

var mailOptions = {
    to: req.body.to,
    from: req.body.from,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    text: req.body.text,
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: req.file.originalname,
            path: req.file.path
        }
    ]
};

mailer.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(res);
  });
});

// Start server
server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
});

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

**The following error is shown:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/server/app.js:51:35
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
at done (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:36:7)
at indicateDone (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:40:51)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:142:11
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:43:9)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at WriteStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:468:14)
```

Comment: paste your code where you use upload.array('attachment'). Write also what  failed when you test  multiple attachements. if there are errors in console then write them too.

Comment: I've update my code. I hope it's clear. Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for update. Now it is clear for me.
Your error means that req.file is undefined. And it is correct.
Check multer docs https://github.com/expressjs/multer:

if you use upload.single then file data is in req.file. But when you use upload.array then, your files data is in req.files (plural form of file).

To fix this problem change in your code req.file to req.files and remember that this is array with files data.

For example orginalname of first file is in req.files[0].originalname

Comment: Thanks. That worked! I now have to find a way to iterate over the array of files and put the attachment(s) in the Sendgrid data. Do you have any ideas how to achieve this? This is what i have so far.  `var mailOptions = {
        to: req.body.to,
        from: req.body.from,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.text,
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: req.files[0].originalname,
                path: req.files[0].path
            }
        ]
    };`

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I wrote below code without test just from head (please dont downvote if there are errors):
var attachementList = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < req.files.length;i++){
  attachementList.push({ filename: req.files[i].originalname, path: req.files[i].path } ] })
}
mailOptions = { to: req.body.to, from: req.body.from, subject: req.body.subject, text: req.body.text, attachments: attachementList };

Comment: Some minor changes to your code. Thanks a lot! `app.post('/api/email', upload.array('attachment', 4), function(req, res, next) {var attachementList = [];for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {attachementList.push({filename: req.files[i].originalname,path: req.files[i].path})}var mailOptions = {to: req.body.to,from: req.body.from,subject: req.body.subject,text: req.body.text,attachments: attachementList}mailer.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res) {if (err) {console.log(err);}console.log(res);});});`

Comment: :) If my answer satisfied you, please check it as accepted. Thanks